# FSM implementation of a debouncing circuit in verilog ( error in time tick)

Tags: verilog, fpga, fsm

I need to solve an issue in FPGA Prototyping By Verilog Examples  [Pong](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470185325)

If its Autor mistake or I'm doing sth wrong 
when i simulate on vivado  i dont find any change in

```
    q_reg <= q_next;    //   ? q_next never initialised ???
   // next-state logic    //  How he wants to set time tick ?
   assign q_next = q_reg + 1;
   // output tick
```

State diagram of a debouncing circuit. is defined as  picture

consider  section
                   // counter to generate 10 ms tick

[image]

```
module db_fsm
   (
    input wire clk, reset,
    input wire sw,
    output reg db
   );

   // symbolic state declaration
   localparam  [2:0]
               zero    = 3'b000,
               wait1_1 = 3'b001,
               wait1_2 = 3'b010,
               wait1_3 = 3'b011,
               one     = 3'b100,
               wait0_1 = 3'b101,
               wait0_2 = 3'b110,
               wait0_3 = 3'b111;

   // number of counter bits (2^N * 20ns = 10ms tick)
   localparam N =19;

   // signal declaration
   reg [N-1:0] q_reg;
   wire [N-1:0] q_next;
   wire m_tick;
   reg [2:0] state_reg, state_next;

   // body

   //=============================================
   // counter to generate 10 ms tick
   //=============================================
   always @(posedge clk)
      q_reg <= q_next;
   // next-state logic
   assign q_next = q_reg + 1;
   // output tick
   assign m_tick = (q_reg==0) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

   //=============================================
   // debouncing FSM
   //=============================================
   // state register
    always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
       if (reset)
          state_reg <= zero;
       else
          state_reg <= state_next;

   // next-state logic and output logic
   always @*
   begin
      state_next = state_reg;  // default state: the same
      db = 1'b0;               // default output: 0
      case (state_reg)
         zero:
            if (sw)
               state_next = wait1_1;
         wait1_1:
            if (~sw)
               state_next = zero;
            else
               if (m_tick)
                  state_next = wait1_2;
         wait1_2:
            if (~sw)
               state_next = zero;
            else
               if (m_tick)
                  state_next = wait1_3;
         wait1_3:
            if (~sw)
               state_next = zero;
            else
               if (m_tick)
                  state_next = one;
         one:
            begin
              db = 1'b1;
              if (~sw)
                 state_next = wait0_1;
            end
         wait0_1:
            begin
               db = 1'b1;
               if (sw)
                  state_next = one;
               else
                 if (m_tick)
                    state_next = wait0_2;
            end
         wait0_2:
            begin
               db = 1'b1;
               if (sw)
                  state_next = one;
               else
                 if (m_tick)
                    state_next = wait0_3;
            end
         wait0_3:
            begin
               db = 1'b1;
               if (sw)
                  state_next = one;
               else
                 if (m_tick)
                    state_next = zero;
            end
         default: state_next = zero;
      endcase
   end

endmodule
```

Comment: Your question seems to have gotten cut off: "when i simulate on vivado i dont find any change in".  How are you testing this code?  What problems or errors are you experiencing?

Comment: @T.J Follow Greg and RahulMenon response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q_next` does not need to be initialized, it is a combinational logic derived from `q_reg`. `q_reg` is not explicitly initialized, therefore it will take the default value.

The default value of a flop on FPGA is `0` but for simulators the default is `X`. The reason for this discrepancy is because Verilog is also used for simulating integrated circuits (IC); who flops can have an initial value that seem random due to the technology node, manufacturing process and variations, temperature, etc.

Since your target is FGPA, the simple solution is to add the line `initial q_reg = {N{1'b0}};` or change `reg [N-1:0] q_reg;` to `reg [N-1:0] q_reg = {N{1'b0}};` Either way of initializing `q_reg` will have you Verilog simulation and FPGA matching.

BTW: for a ASIC as the target, the FPGA solution will not work (initializer is ignored by ASIC synthesizers). An ASIC solution would be to add a reset condition (synchronous or asynchronous) to the always block that assigns the flop. The ASIC solution does work for FPGA, however FPGA's typically have a limited number (if any) of flops with asynchronous reset/set

Comment: (@ Greg) Though the reset solution is the preferred way for ASIC , the counter ( at the max,  after the first few clock cycles ) will  settle into a random value and after the first rollover start generating regular m_ticks. Shouldn't that be good enough as the main concern for debouncing is to get a regular m_tick ? The first m_tick being ignorable .

Comment: @RahulMenon, In the case of this design, wasting up to 10ms waiting for a regular m_tick might be acceptable, but that would be a small exception In the overall best practice of ASIC design. For most ASIC designs, 10ms is too much wasted time. Plus a typical ASIC has hundreds or thousands and sometimes millions of flops most of which are used for control logic. An unknown state in control can produce unpredictable and harmful behavior. The only place in ASIC I've seen intentional flops without async reset is in high-speed data pipeline where it is guaranteed to not effect control logic.